# Can not start a QTcp Server

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qtcpserver

I'm having a weird error. I'm trying to establish a connection to a server but the Server doesn't seem to start. Here's the Server.cpp:

```
Server::Server (QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
    {
        }
void Server::start()
{
    QHostAddress pHost;
    pHost.setAddress("192.168.10.10"); //Setting the Address of the Server to the Address of the target system
    QString printAddress;
    printAddress = pHost.toString();
    printf(QString("starting Host under " + printAddress + " \n").toStdString().c_str()); 
    if (this->listen(pHost, 8016))
    {
        printf(QString("Server started and Listening \n").toStdString().c_str());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Server could not be started \n");
    }
}
```

In my main.cpp I instantiate the Server and call the method start.

```
Server pServer; 
pServer.start();
```

this->listen(pHost, 8016) seems to be returning false because i get "Server could not be started" printed. What am I doing wrong? Why does the Server not start?

By the Way the Address 192.168.10.10 is the Address of another Computer in the local Network. Maybe that's why I'm getting an Error ?

I'm trying to establish a connection to that Device.
Any Help is highly appreciated !! Thank you !!

Comment: Yes, you can't listen on the address of another computer, you need to use your own address

Comment: well that makes sense thanks! how can I connect to that Device with that specific Address though? I'm trying to send Data to the other Device.

Comment: The client connects to the server, you can't do it the other way round

Comment: Re. `"how can I connect to that Device with that specific Address"` -- is that device listening for connections?

Comment: No, the other Device is connected to mine with a LAN Cable. I tried to make the other device listen with this Code: pHost.setAddress("192.168.10.10")  this->listen(pHost, 8016) but it does not work

Comment: I actually habe a class called CLIENT. It connects successfully to the Server and grabs a file from my local Device and tries to send it to the Server. If the Connection is successful it means the Server is Listening. The Question is how to make the Server handle the incoming Connection and write the Data on the remote Device??